# Positive real vs. natural numbers in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data

When looking at data on answers to questions on a slider scale, which will yield positive real numbers, is there any possible scenario where one would discretize the data and thus turn it into real numbers for further processing in machine learning models? Maybe I'm completely off here, but wouldn't one just loose information, in all cases?

---

Edit: To boil my question down: is there any reason why one would get rid of decimals in feature values in a random forest? I know this may sound incredibly rudimental, but I'm going through a lot of student-papers right now and in one paper, someone casually mentions this procedure and I'm just unsure if I am missing something or if they are just in the wrong.